# Como instalar e utilizar o Chromepdf?

Tags: php

Alguém poderia me ajudar a instalar o chromepdf que se encontra no github?
[link do chromePdf](https://github.com/abalozz/chrome-pdf-php)

Comment: O link que você colocou dá as instruções de instalação e uso. Em qual parte você está tendo dificuldade? O que já tentou?

Comment: Bem ,eu baixei o projeto do GitHub coloquei na mesma pasta que ou meu projeto ,porem  mesmo assim não funcion.

Comment: Só é possível através do composer ?

Comment: Também tem como instalar sem o composer. Mas se você não sabe como (lidar com autoload, namespaces etc), o mais fácil é usar composer. Esse script foi publicado pensando nesse uso. Em último caso você pode pegar [o trecho de código que de fato faz o trabalho](https://github.com/abalozz/chrome-pdf-php/blob/master/src/ChromePdf.php#L50) e usar direto no seu código...

Comment: O arquivo onde a class foi feita e copia pro meu projeto  basicamente ?

Comment: Pensei que seria só incluir e fazer a instancia da classe

Comment: Não é só incluir porque tem namespace, antes de usar você precisa dar um `use` do namespace.